# How to Git Cherry Pick when file position has changed from one directory to other

Tags: git

Due to addition machine dependent changes, folders got created in latest release

Before:

```
A/B/C/file1.txt
```

After:

```
A/B/C/{Machine}/file1.txt
```

I got a fix for latest version i.e

```
{A/B/C/{Machine}/file1.txt}
```

How can I cherry pick latest to before version?

Comment: What is wrong with a simple merge? If you properly renamed the file, git should be able to resolve it.

Comment: I did a rename in patch file and merged it. For me it was only a file, but I thought there should be a generalized way for edits in multiple files.

Comment: sure, `git merge` is the generalized way for doing it.  1) create a branch before rename, 2) modify files, 3) merge with master, which has renames. it should work.